# How to call AngularJS directive function to another controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, directive

**custom.js**

```
function config($stateProvider){
     $stateProvider
        .state('test_page', {
            abstract: true,
            url: "/test-page",
            controller: "testController"
            templateUrl: "test.html",
        });
}

function testController($scope){
     $scope.edit= function(){
          alert("You have clicked edit icon");
     }         
}

function anotherController($scope){
     $scope.copy = function(){
          alert("Holla... You have clicked copy icon");
     }
}



function iboxTools($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: 'views/common/ibox_tools.html',
        controller: function($scope, $element) {
            // Function for collapse ibox
            $scope.showhide = function() {
                var ibox = $element.closest('div.ibox');
                var icon = $element.find('i:first');
                var content = ibox.find('div.ibox-content');
                content.slideToggle(200);
                // Toggle icon from up to down
                icon.toggleClass('fa-chevron-up').toggleClass('fa-chevron-down');
                ibox.toggleClass('').toggleClass('border-bottom');
                $timeout(function() {
                    ibox.resize();
                    ibox.find('[id^=map-]').resize();
                }, 50);
            };
            // Function for close ibox
            $scope.closebox = function() {
                var ibox = $element.closest('div.ibox');
                ibox.remove();
            };
        }
    };
}



angular
        .module('myModule')
        .config(config)
        .controller('testController', testController)
        .controller('anotherController', anotherController)
        .directive('iboxTools', iboxTools)
```

**test.html**

```
<div ibox-tools></div>
/*more html */
```

**ibox_tools.html**

```
<div class="ibox-tools" uib-dropdown>
    <a ng-click="showhide()"> <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
    <a ng-click="copy()">
        <i class="fa fa-file"></i>
    </a>
    <a ng-click="edit()">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
    </a>
    <a ng-click="closebox()"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
</div>
```

Above I have posted my code. Here directive template `copy()` function not working because I have written `showhide()` and `closebox()` functions within the directive controller, `edit()` function in my current page `testController` and last `copy()` function written `anotherController`

Please check above my code. Why not calling `anotherController` `copy()` function in my current page controller?

Sorry for my bad English :(

Answer (score 0):

You can't call the function simply in another controller if it is not related to your directive/controller. So to achieve this you can declare it as $rootScope function instead of $scope or use events.

```
 function testController($rootScope){
    $rootScope.edit= function(){
      alert("You have clicked edit icon");
    }         
 }

 function anotherController($rootScope){
    $rootScope.copy = function(){
      alert("Holla... You have clicked copy icon");
   }  
 }
```

Using $rootScope everytime is not good but in some cases you can proceed.

Or we can use events

```
 function anotherController($rootScope){
     $scope.$on('copyEvent', function(event, arguments) {
        alert("Holla... You have clicked copy icon");
     });   
   }  
 }
```

To trigger that event just from child just $emit

```
$scope.$emit('copyEvent', arguments);
```

Hope this helps. Thanks !